# networkx place nodes with specific position

Tags: python, networkx

I want to add multiple types of nodes in different position, I used the following code:

```
g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
plt.figure(len(data))
nx.draw(g, pos=posDict, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

where the `data` looks like this:

```
Data(pos=[3, 2], x=[3, 1080, 1920], c=[3], edge_index=[2, 6], edge_attr=[6, 1])
```

And the posDict has the nodes and the distance between them:

```
{0: array([0.740365, 0.126852]), 1: array([0.755729, 0.473148]), 2: array([0.917969, 0.469907])}
```

By doing:

```
print(g.nodes())
```

I get:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> [0, 1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
> 7, 8, 9] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [0, 1, 2, 3,
> 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] [0, 1, 2, 3]
> .....

I got this error:

> NetworkXError: Node 3 has no position.

How can I add nodes to a graph in a specific location x and y?

Comment: Can you include the result of `print(g.nodes())`? From the data I'm currently not sure how many nodes your graph has. In general, you are on the right path. You could also get a posDict from any method (e.g. random layout) and then modify it. I guess your posDict currently simply has fewer nodes than your graph has.

Comment: Your networkx graph has way more nodes, I'll guess each of these lists `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` is a node or you have some loop around the code which you shows us. In any case you have more than 3 nodes and your PosDict only has 3 entries. Hence you get an error for the fourth node (node with id 3). How should all the other nodes be positioned?